# recoil__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management, recoiljs

I was writing this simple atom

```js
const userState = atom({
  key: "userState",
  default: {},
});
```

then I got this error
`recoil__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...) is not a function` when I try to use that atom

```js
const [user, setUser] = useRecoilState(userState);
```

**update:** when I updated to 0.0.13 I got this error instead `Object(...) is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used brackets to import `atom` and `useRecoilState` that solved my issue. Which means

```js
import {atom} from "recoil" // in atom file
import {useRecoilState} from "recoil" // in component/s file/s
```